# Symfony Sonata Admin - Text input vs List Dropdown on an Object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, sonata-admin

I have an object call 'Competition' with a to_string function to have an object name that i want my search input going to.

i want to have a text input with search function based on the name of the object competition.

I try this, but impossible to use.
(i don't know with a search based on the object name)
THANKS

```
/**
     * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('name')
            ->add('country')
            ->add('contact')
            ->add('organisation')
            ->add('competition', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
            'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
             if (empty($value['value'])) {
            return;
             }
        $queryBuilder->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.competition', $alias), 'u');
        $queryBuilder->where('u.competition LIKE :competition');
        $queryBuilder->setParameter('competition', '%'.$value['value'].'%');
        return true;
        },
        'field_type' => 'text'
        ))

            ->add('descriptionlongnat', null, array('label' => 'Description national'))
            ->add('descriptionlongen', null, array('label' => 'Description english'))
            ->add('category')
            ->add('preservation', null, array('label' =
```

Comment: thanks to help me on this

Comment: i don' know which value i have to put in the querybuilder ?? for my 'competition' object

Comment: CAN YOU HELP ME

Comment: I need  jquery help